# Delaying code execution without crash

Tags: java, android

I am looking for a way to delay my app from creating and displaying toasts. I am using a few different intervals, the largest being 5 minutes. I am using sleep to delay the program but after about a minute the app will crash. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed just let me know! Thanks!!

Comment: You can use something like an AsyncTask or a thread for that just specify the Thread.sleep(milliseconds);

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `postDelayed` of an Handler to execute a code later in the main UI thread:

```
int delay = 2000;

Handler handler = new Handler();

// to execute in 2 sec
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "Showing toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}, delay);
```

Comment: Use view.postDelayed() to skip the new Handler() part.

Answer (score 2):

This is an AsyncTask that shows a Toast after 5 seconds of it being called.

```
public class ToastAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {
        private Context mContext;

        public SaveAuctionAsyncTask(Context mContext)
        {
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
        {
            Thread.sleep(300000); //300000 is 5 minutes
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Showing toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

The way you execute an the **ToastAsyncTask** from an **Activity** is like this:

```
ToastAsyncTask toastAsyncTask = new ToastAsyncTask (this);
toastAsyncTask .execute();
```

Comment: Shouldn´t Toast.show() be called from the main thread? Then this snippet would throw and exception and crash

Comment: Thank you for noticing that, but it is allowed in the onPostExecute method

Comment: @NannuoLei his code is fine, you can run simple UI event's from onPostExecute just fine

Comment: @Arlind When I use doInBackground multiple times everything done in onPostExecute happens at once. Anyway to avoid this?